# Get a segmentation fault when running my jest tests in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I just suddenly couldn't run my jest tests, it says there is a segmentation fault. Looks like this:

> npm run test:unit -- '/src/components/Main.spec.ts' --watchAll

> app@0.1.0 test:unit
> TZ=UTC vue-cli-service test:unit "/src/components/Main.spec.ts" "--watchAll"

> zsh: segmentation fault  npm run test:unit --  --watchAll

I've tried googling but can't manage to understand how to fix it. Anyone out there that knows? :)

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: same here... I'm trying to use `--watch` and I get this `[1]    18830 segmentation fault  ./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service test:unit --watch`

Comment: Did any of you find a solution? I'm in the same pit-hole now

Comment: I was seeing the segmentation fault message too, after removing the --watch option my tests ran and I got a more useful message:  TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

Comment: Googling 'TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.' led to uninstalling vue-jest and installing vue3-jest and updating the transform in jest.config.js The test all ran after that, but turning watch back on still causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: I am using `vitest` for testing and I solved the issue by disabling the threads. I am not familiar with `jest` but maybe you can disable threads, similarly.